# How do I generate a SELECT menu from Django's localflavor.us.models.USStateField utility?

Tags: django, django-models, drop-down-menu, view

I'm using Python 3.7 and Django.  I'm using the "localflavor.us.models" package to store a state field in my model ...

```
from localflavor.us.models import USStateField
from phonenumber_field.modelfields import PhoneNumberField
...

class UsLocation(models.Model):
    address_1 = models.CharField(_("address"), max_length=128)
    address_2 = models.CharField(_("address cont'd"), max_length=128, blank=True)

    city = models.CharField(_("city"), max_length=64, null=False)
    state = USStateField(_("state"), null=False)
    zip_code = models.CharField(_("zip code"), max_length=10, null=False)
```

My question is, in a Django form, I'd like to create a select drop-down menu that mirrors a state selection.  Is there a way I can get all the states provided by USStateField in some field in my view's context?  I'm open to using another Django utility to validate the state.  I'd prefer not to hard-code everything myself (if only to save on writing code).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a widget in `USStateSelect` in `localflavor.us.forms`. You can use it in forms like this

```
from localflavor.us.forms import USStateSelect

class MyForm(forms.Form):
    state = froms.CharField(widget=USStateSelect)
```

It will render to a select dropdown with all US states as choices.

Comment: what if i want to select a list of all countries?